# dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GULObjectSwizzler

Tags: ios

Im using these frameworks in cocoapods:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Performance'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

and latest GoogleSignIn but I add it manually to my project
after pod update there's an error when I run my app:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GULObjectSwizzler
```

Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/150D4F83-7653-4556-8ABF-98E0904B9EF7/ABC.app/ABC
  Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/150D4F83-7653-4556-8ABF-98E0904B9EF7/ABC.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities
 in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/150D4F83-7653-4556-8ABF-98E0904B9EF7/ABC.app/ABC

Comment: please share your problem in brief details and what type of framework you are using

Comment: I've added above

Comment: Did you clean your build folder and try again?

Comment: Yes, I tried many times, clean, detele xcode derived data, reinstall pods..

Comment: i suggest you that you use cocoapods instead manually if you have any cocoapods error then i help you to solve it

Comment: I also tried using GoogleSignIn through cocoapods but it still error

Comment: Tap target and check the build settings, Is there any unwanted frameworks added in the header search path?

Comment: I started having the same problem. Have you gotten any resolution to this?

Comment: I have updated GoogleSignIn and that has not been a problem. It is only when I update to the latest Firebase libs that I get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I removed Firebase Performance and it works well

Answer (score 0):

For further reference: I too had this problem and solved it by adding the `Firebase/Performance` Pod to an app extension that was bundled with the main application as well.